# How to update Microsoft.Bot.Builder version in bot framework composer?

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

Current version of my Bot is "4.15.0". How to update latest version in bot framework composer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible in Bot composer at the moment !!!
Open the application in Visual studio go to "Manage NuGet package" & update to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the packages then there are few ways to do this.

One way is to use Visual Studio and update the version using the NuGet Manager

If you're using Visual Studio **Code**, like I am, there is an extension called **NuGet Package Manger GUI** that you can use and do it yourself.

Another possible way is to just change the version number in .csproj file
[image]